# C++ odd template issue

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class with a nested type, in order to allow class templates share a static mutex:

```
template<int ID = 0>
class single_lockable
{
    static std::mutex M_mu;
protected:
    class single_lock :public std::lock_guard<std::mutex>
    {
    public:
        single_lock()
            :std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(M_mu)
        {
        }
    };
};

template<int ID>
std::mutex single_lockable<ID>::M_mu;
```

And a stream wrapper to guarantee thread safety:

```
template<ostream& stream, int ID = 0>
class thread_safe_stream_wrapper :public single_lockable<ID>
{
    ...
    typedef typename single_lockable<ID>::single_lock single_lock;

public:
    ...
    thread_safe_stream_wrapper<stream,ID>& operator<<(const std::string& Arg)
    {
        M_stringbuilder << Arg;
        if (Arg[Arg.length() - 1] == '\n')
        {
            single_lock lock();
            stream << M_stringbuilder.str();
            M_stringbuilder.str(std::string());
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

thread_safe_stream_wrapper<std::cout> thread_safe_cout;
thread_safe_stream_wrapper<std::cerr> thread_safe_cerr;
```

However, I'm getting troubles on     `single_lock lock();`:

```
GCC: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'thread_safe_stream_wrapper<stream, ID>::single_lock lock()'
MSVC: warning C4930: 'single_lockable<0>::single_lock lock(void)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

And if I change it to this, it works well:

```
single_lock lock;
```

Could you explain why is this happening? I don't think there is any difference between `A a;` and `A a();` if A is a class. Am I missing some important syntax points? Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think there is any difference between `A a;` and `A a();` if `A` is a class

You are wrong.

> Am I missing some important syntax points?

`single_lock lock()` is a function declaration. Yes, even inside a function body!

Indeed, the error message suggests this in its text:

> prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Yes, it was! Write `single_lock lock;`

This is related to [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), but not as complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much:) But I don't quite know why `A a();` is not causing ambiguity?

Comment: @babel92: Why would it cause ambiguity? The language defines `A a()` to be a declaration of a function called `a` returning an `A`. It's as simple as that! The instantiation of a class type with no constructor parameters shall not include a `()`.

Comment: Oh this has been confusing me for a long time! If I use `A a()` then no instance is constructed at all! A lot of thanks.

Comment: @babel92: That's right. It declares a [non-existent] function, instead, just like when you write `int func();`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
single_lock lock();
```

Use

```
single_lock lock;
```

Or for bonus C++11-ness

```
auto lock = single_lock{};
```

The three are equivalent, the first form is prone to being interpreted as a function declaration (the "most vexing parse" - the rule that if the parser CAN interpret it as a function delcaration, it WILL above all else).

See here: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) Would you mind explaining a bit more about the brace syntax in the C++11 approach? It looks really strange to me...

Comment: It's part of what's called the uniform initialisation syntax. This is a good answer to refer to: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax